# What is the C++ equivalent of the % or .format operator in Python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, fmt

I am quite new to C++ and I am writing a program that needs an operator that does the same thing as the Python % operator. Is there any equivalent in C++?

Comment: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

Comment: Do you need to use a format string in particular, or would other formatted output suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has several ways to do IO, mostly for historical reasons. Whichever style your project uses should be used consistently.

1. C-style IO: printf, sprintf, etc.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main () {
  const char *name = "world";
  // other specifiers for int, float, formatting conventions are avialble
  printf("Hello, %s\n", name); 
}
```

2. C++ style IO: iostreams

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string name = "world";
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
}
```

3. Libraries/C++20 std::format:

Pre C++20 quite a few people have provided their own formatting libraries. One of the better ones is [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). C++ adopted this kind of formatting as `[std::format][2]`

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string name = "world";
  std::cout << std::format("Hello, {}", name) << std::endl;
}
```

Notice that format produces format-strings, so it works with both ways to do IO, and/or other custom approaches, but if you use C-style IO it would probably be mostly weird to layer std::format on top, where the printf specifier would also work.

Answer (score 7):

The C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) library serves this purpose:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <format>
>  
> int main() {
>     std::cout << std::format("Hello {}!\n", "world");
> }
> ```

For more info and guides on how to use it, see:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format
- https://www.bfilipek.com/2020/02/extra-format-cpp20.html
- https://www.zverovich.net/2019/07/23/std-format-cpp20.html
- [How can I use C++20 std::format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024390/how-can-i-use-c20-stdformat)

However, `<format>` isn't provided in some standard library implementations yet — see [C++20 library features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features).  In the meantime you can use https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt, which is equivalent (and was the inspiration for `<format>`).

Comment: When I try to compile your code in VS 2019, I get these three errors: cannot open "format", namespace std has no member format and: cannot open include file "format": no such file or directory

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561306/c20-support-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%i", 123456789);
```

Comment: Not really the same as in python

Comment: @smac89 c++ isn't python (also it's a lot better than python)

Comment: I know this (although I'm not sure about "better"), I'm just saying that the way you have used `%` is not the same as what OP is looking to emulate, as in python. The answer you have given is more similar to how one would use the `{}` format in python, than the way `%` works in python

Comment: Then maybe OP should instead ask "why doesn't python look as good as c++ does"

Comment: Actually this works the same as `%` operator in . Nvm my previous comment. I've long been away from python and C++

Comment: Oh good, now we can ignore the part where you stated that python is better than c++. Finally.